# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException , Error with Scanner

Tags: java

I'm stuck on an error for hours while practising Java. When I enter the price with decimal points I get this Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
    at grocerystore.GroceryStore.main(GroceryStore.java:19)
C:\Users\aslan\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
```

My code:

```
package grocerystore;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author aslan
 */
public class GroceryStore {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double [] prices = new double [5];
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 5 prices: ");
        prices[0] = in.nextDouble();
        prices[1] = in.nextDouble();
        prices[2] = in.nextDouble();
        prices[3] = in.nextDouble();
        prices[4] = in.nextDouble();
        double total = prices[0] + prices[1] + prices[2] + prices[4];
        System.out.printf("the tot1al of all 5 items is:$%5.2f" +total);
    }
}
```

Can any one help ???

Comment: Give an example of what you are inputting; any number formatted as x.y should work.

Comment: System.out.printf("the tot1al of all 5 items is:$%5.2f" +total); Changed  it to System.out.println("the total of all 5 items is: +total"); but the same problem occurs . IM entering x.y or x.yy but it doesn't work

Comment: @AslanAli I did not mean x.y literally-put in one number followed by a decimal and then another number. examples include 2.2, 31.0, and 11.2

Comment: Try to use comma instead of dot in input (like 12,38) and see what happens; BTW, is there any possible reason why total doesn't add `prices[3]`?

Comment: the comma works !!! thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything other than a number or a full stop for `in.nextDouble()` will throw an `InputMismatchException`. So try to ensure that you only put numbers and full stops in.

Also, `printf()`'s arguments are a format string and then the arguments. Since you have a format specifier in the `String` you have supplied, it must have an argument to match. So the correct syntax is 
`.out.printf("the tot1al of all 5 items is:$%5.2f", total);`

Also, I notice that you missed `prices[3]`. A working solution:

```
        double[] prices = new double[5];

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 5 prices: ");

        prices[0] = in.nextDouble();
        prices[1] = in.nextDouble();
        prices[2] = in.nextDouble();
        prices[3] = in.nextDouble();
        prices[4] = in.nextDouble();

        double total = prices[0] + prices[1] + prices[2] + prices[3] + prices[4];

        System.out.printf("the tot1al of all 5 items is:$%5.2f", total);


Output:

    Enter 5 prices: 
    .0
    .1
    .2
    .3
    .4
    the tot1al of all 5 items is:$ 1.00
```